# Как вернуть объект, который попал на место перетянутого в jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, sortable

Например я перетащил один li на другой, стандартно ui.item берется объект, но это выходит тот объект, который я перетаскивал, а как поймать тот, на который перетаскиваю? см. мой jsfiddle: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/jCMuQ/10/). Тут надо понимать, что если я перетащу 1-ый элемент на место 3-его, то вместо 1-го становится 2-й элемент, т.е. индексные заморочки тут не особо прокатят. Нужно взять именно те два элемента, которые изначально планировалось поменять.

Comment: В этом случае нет объекта, **на который** перетаскивается элемент. Есть, так сказать, место, кудо он как бы вклинивается. Можно найти те объекты, которые теперь являются его "соседями".

Comment: Да я понимаю что экстрасенсорные способности в ``jQuery`` не особо развиты, но все же, конечно я пересмотрел все события sortable, увы, там нет решения.

Comment: Ладно, пусть вопрос останется, не хочу удалять, так как кто его знает, возможно у кого-то когда-нть тоже такое желание возникнет, может кто-то решит, а вот в моей глобальной задаче я поступлю иначе, а именно использую метод unserialize для отправки данных на сервер, т.е. всех вместо конкретных элементов, к сожалению у меня возникли трудности с рассериализацией данных, вопрос здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/145355/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-unserialize-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5